# Unable to get the resource-id when running uiautomator events in an adb shell

Tags: android, shell

we are running uiautomator events in an adb shell.It should dump all the Accessibility Events but is not giving the resource-id

```
08-03 12:22:13.520 EventType: TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED; EventTime: 185419; PackageName: com.nimbuzz; MovementGranularity: 0; Action: 0 [ ClassName: android.widget.Button; Text: [IÂ´m new to Nimbuzz]; ContentDescription: null; ItemCount: -1; CurrentItemIndex: -1; IsEnabled: true; IsPassword: false; IsChecked: false; IsFullScreen: false; Scrollable: false; BeforeText: null; FromIndex: -1; ToIndex: -1; ScrollX: -1; ScrollY: -1; MaxScrollX: -1; MaxScrollY: -1; AddedCount: -1; RemovedCount: -1; ParcelableData: null ]; recordCount: 0RemovedCount: -1; ParcelableData: null ]; recordCount: 0
```

I need a resource-id property.
Resource used:
Android version 4.4

Any help will be highly appreciated.